# Get day name from weekday index

Tags: python

Given a date `datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)` I can get the weekday index:

```
>>> datetime.date(2015, 9, 30).weekday()
>>> 2
```

Now, given a weekday index `2` How can I get the week name?

I know I can define a `list`:

```
day_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thrusday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

And the call

```
>>> day_names[2]
>>> 'Wednesday'
```

Is there a built-in python function to do this?

**Edit**

I also know I can do this:

```
>>> datetime.date(2015, 9, 30).strftime('%A')
>>> 'Wednesday'
```

But the line above assumes I still have the `datetime.date` object. Now I just have an `index`

Comment: The answers in the duplicate fail to mention the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module though, which may or may not provide an easier API for dealing with weekdays, depending on the use case.

Comment: Looks like for your use case, `calendar.day_name[idx]` should do the trick. Make sure to read the notes on localization and starting point of weeks though.

Comment: @LukasGraf I didn't reached that part of the docs. Thanks for your comment, please consider posting an answer.